# R TCLTK not loading on windows

Tags: r, tcl

I have installed R on countless windows machines and never had a problem with the tcltk package until now.
I have freshly installed R 3.3.2 onto Windows 10 Pro v1607 and can't load tcltk. I used the windows install binaries from CRAN, so no custom builds.

```
capabilities("tcltk")
```

returns TRUE. When I try to load tcltk:

```
library("tcltk")
```

I get:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/tcltk/libs/x64/tcltk.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’
```

Navigating to the location of the DLL confirms that it is there. This fails when calling both x64 and i386 versions of R. I have tried running as admin and same thing. I also tried rolling back to version 3.3.1 and had the same issues.

This PC has an AMD FX-8120 processor.

I couldn't find much on R tcltk problems on Windows. Any ideas would be great.
Cheers

EDIT: added info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Comment: Strange. Check if tcl/tk itself is working without R: Find the `wish.exe` of tcltk and start it. Does it work (= open a window?). Does the output of `puts $auto_path` in the wish console contain the path from your error message above?

Comment: https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-TclTk-does-not-work_002e

Comment: An open bug around `tcltk` is not known currently: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=tcltk&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&query_format=specific

Comment: So, wish.exe loads and the output of pute $auto_path is:
{C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5} {C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/Tcl/lib} {C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/Tcl/lib/tk8.5} {C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/Tcl/lib/tk8.5/ttk}. This does not contain the path of my error

Comment: OK, TCL/Tk works, but the package DLL does not load. Can you post the `sessionInfo()` output please after you have started a fresh R session. Which GUI/IDE are you using? Is the environment variable `MY_TCLTK` defined (see my link two comments before)? If yes to which value? I have installed R3.3.2 64 Bit on Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) and the package `tcltk` does work (can be loaded). I cannot test if Windows 10 or R is causing the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with output from sessionInfo() I use R Studio. I changed the MY_TCLTK variable to the path that tcl was installed with R and now it works. MY_TCLTK was "Yes". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem do the following tests:

Test the Tcl/Tk installation of R:

1. Find and start `wish85.exe` which is contained in one of the sub folders of the R installation ("85" is the version number and my differ depending on your R version).
2. An empty Tk window must pop up and a tcl/tk console must open.
   If not the installation is damaged or parts have been deleted
   (reinstall it)

Check if R is using the right Tcl/Tk version:

1. Check the value of the environment variable `MY_TCLTK`
2. If it is defined: Does the path point to the bin folder of Tcl/Tk?
   If not: Fix it.

   If it is not defined: It should work out of the box but you could
   set the value to the bin folder.

Source:

https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-TclTk-does-not-work_002e

Answer (score 0):

`MY_TCLTK` was defined as "Yes" in my environment variables. I changed it to the location of the tcl exe that was installed with R and it works now.